# How to list specific records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am currently working on a university assignment where it is asking me to write an SQL statement to list all the assigned reviewers by their name and their corresponding rating for a specific book of my choice. I have chosen `bookId` `1`. However, when I try to list the reviewers by their name and the corresponding rating for the specific book, I get duplicate records. I was wondering what I am doing wrong as I am new to SQL server and having a bit of difficulty.

**Report Table**

```
reportID  reviewerID  bookID  rating  dateRecorded
--------------------------------------------------
30        1000        1       4       2020-02-09
31        1000        2       3       2020-02-09
32        1001        1       2       2020-02-09
33        1001        2       3       2020-02-09
```

**Reviewer Table**

```
reviewerID  firstName  lastName  phoneNumber  emailAddress
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1000        Leon       James     412587423    leonjames@gmail.com
1001        Mark       Jeffrey   489521782    markjeffrey@gmail.com
```

**SELECT Query**:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, bookID, rating
FROM Reviewer, Report
WHERE bookID = 1;
```

**Book Table**

```
bookID  bookTitle             authorID
--------------------------------------
1       Fifty Shades of Grey  100
2       Fifty Shades Darker   101
3       Fifty Shades Freed    102
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please refrain from using pictures unless absolutely necessary. In this case it would help if you simply posted the query and example data as text in the question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: You're doing an old style cross join instead do a new style inner join.

Comment: Since you are still learning, please also learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

SQL need you to say how he can join the table.
In you query you are calling data from two different tables, Reviewer and Report, but you are not saying "what they have in common".

```
Select firstName, lastName, bookId, rating
from reviewer rev INNER JOIN report rep ON REV.reviewerID = REP.reviewerID
where rep.bookId = 1
```

REV.reviewerID = REP.reviewerID says to the db which record select from all the available.
The query is raw now. Probably you will be asked also to insert the title of the book.
There are other things to be added, but they will come step by step.